# PHP files not displaying

Tags: php, apache, web

I am trying to display my php files but all I seem to get is the source code.
I am running mac 10.7.5
I have installed MAMP and added a file (test.php) to the htdocs folder. I have turned the apache server on.

the code in the file is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>:-)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      echo "<p>Hello, world. I'm a php file.</p>";
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and when I point my browser (chrome) to this file it shows the source code exactly as above.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add the php support to your httpd.conf file

Comment: Hi Sebas, thanks for your answer. I am a bit of a noob. How would I do this?

Comment: What URL are you entering ? It should be something like `http://localhost...`. Also make sure php files have the right file extension.

Comment: check in var/log/apache2/error.log for errors, php is enabled?

Comment: Are you browsing to the file using `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`?

Comment: I am using 
file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php

Comment: Guessed as much :) . That's the problem and it's absolutely normal it's showing you the code. Find the equivalent URL to access it through the web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're accessing the script using the file protocol. I guessed as much as I've hit the snag more than once after some late night coding :) .

Try accessing it using the address such as `http://localhost/yourfolder/test.php`. The part after localhost is relative to htdocs. If MAMP is up and running this will trigger an HTTP request to Apache and get PHP to interpret the file.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! how stupid of me... you have saved me from pulling my hair out!

Comment: Great. Happy to avoid someone else going bald ;) . Click the tick icon to the left to indicate you've accepted the answer and have a nice day.